# return PHP data as JSON Object

Tags: javascript, php, json, getjson

I have a PHP script that has to return 3 things for all the files containing in a specific directory.

1. filename
2. filesize
3. Filecreation time

I am able to echo these three values for each file but I want to return all this data in JSON format. What is the best way to convert all this data into JSON format?

```
function listAllFiles($dir)
{
    $format = "d/m/y h:m";
    $filesInfo;
    if (is_dir($dir))
   {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir))
        {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
           {
               if ($file != "." && $file != "..") 
               {   
                   echo findFileSize($dir.'/'.$file)."      ".date($format, filemtime($dir.'/'.$file))."     ";
                   echo $file.'<br>';

               }     

           } 
         }
     closedir($dh);


   }
    else {
       print 'folder not found';
    }
}
```

Comment: Best way is to use [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), but how are you getting those data elements anyway?

Comment: 1) Show us what you have tried so far. 2) Show the code 3) Have you tried any Googling like PHP Script to json object?

Comment: I have added the php code...

Comment: Build an array of the values rather than echoing them..... json_encode that array to give a string which you then echo to the front-end

Comment: @MarkBaker should it be a normal array or associative array?

Comment: I'd recommend a 2d array with an enumerated entry for each file, and the file details (name/size/date/etc) as associative

Comment: hmmmm... It's a better option.. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Functions**

> 1. filename

[Use `glob()` to find the files in a directory](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

> 2. filesize

[Use `filesize()` to find the size of a file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php)

> 3. Filecreation time

[Use `filectime()` to find the last creation time of a file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php)

> What is the best way to convert all this data into JSON format?

[Use `json_encode()` to convert a PHP array to a JSON array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

**Code Sample**

```
function listAllFiles($dir){
    if(!isdir($dir)) { print "Folder not found"; return; }

    $files = glob($dir);
    $arr = array();
    foreach($files as $file){
        $file = array();

        //Get filename
        $file["name"] = $file;

        //Get filesize
        $file["size"]= filesize($file);

        //Get file creation time
        $file["creation_time"] = filectime($file);

        array_push($arr, $file);
    }

    $json = json_encode($arr);
    return $json;
}

echo listAllFiles("/folder/");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 simple json functions in PHP `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`

`json_encode()` converts a PHP Array or Object into a JSON string, so create an array or object to contain all your data and then echo the result of the `json_encode()` back to the calling app.

```
function listAllFiles($dir) {

    $results = array();
    $results['error'] = false;

    $format = "d/m/y h:m";
    $filesInfo;
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
               if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {   

                   // create an object to hold data for this file
                   $o = new stdClass();
                   $o->filesize = findFileSize($dir.'/'.$file)
                   $o->filedate = date($format, filemtime($dir.'/'.$file));
                   $o->filename = $file;

                   // put this object into the results array
                   $results[] = $o;
               }     
            } 
        }
        closedir($dh);
   } else {
       $results['error'] = true;
       $results['err_msg'] = 'folder not found';
    }

    return $results;
}


$result = listAllFiles('a/b/c');
echo json_encode($result);
```